# Showing maps (OSM) in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++

is there an easy way to show a map (eg. OpenStreetMap) in Visual C++?. I have searched but didn't find any solution. I just want to show the map, click in any place of it and return the coordinates.
Thank you.